# Unexpected Behavior When Escaping Backslashes JS

Tags: javascript, windows, filepath

so i'm making a simple function that separates the file name and the directory path. I believe there is an easier way with node's Path module but I thought i'd do it myself for this project.

so the problem is when i'm writing a backslash character in a string, I'm escaping them in the string like "directory\AnothaDirectory". It runs, but the double "\" and the "\\" used in order to escape are still remaining in the strings after they are parsed. ex: "C:\\Documents\Newsletters".

I have tried both to use single backslahses, which throws compiler errors as one could expect. but I have also tried to use forward slashes. what could be the reason the backslashes are not being escaped?

```
function splitFileNameFromPath(path,slashType){

    let pathArray = path.split(slashType),
        fileName = pathArray[pathArray.length - 1],
        elsIndexes = pathArray.length - 1,
        pathSegs = pathArray.slice(0, elsIndexes);              

    let dirPath = pathSegs.join(slashType);
    //adds an extra slash after drive name and colon e.g."C:\\"   
    dirPath = dirPath.replace( new RegExp("/\\/","ug"), "\\" )
    //removes illegal last slash
    let pathSeg = pathSegs.slice(0,-1)
    return [dirPath, fileName]
}

let res = splitFileNameFromPath("C:\\\\Documents\\Newsletters\\Summer2018.pdf","\\");
console.log(res)
```

Comment: \\ in string and regex is single slash \ because it's escape character and it's escaped. this just do nothing `dirPath = dirPath.replace( new RegExp("/\\/","ug"), "\\" )`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some moments in this code I do not understand.

1. `"C:\\\\Documents\\Newsletters\\Summer2018.pdf"` (i.e. `"C:\\Documents\Newsletters\Summer2018.pdf"`) does not seem like a valid Windows path as there are no double slashes after the drive letter usually used (it is not like in the URL `'https://...'`).
2. `new RegExp("/\\/","ug")` is equal to `/\/\//gu` and does not match anythhing.
3. The result of `let pathSeg = pathSegs.slice(0,-1)` is not used at all.

It seems to me this code is enough to achive the task:

```js
'use strict';

function splitFileNameFromPath(path, slashType) {
  const pathArray = path.split(slashType),
        fileName = pathArray.pop(),
        dirPath = pathArray.join(slashType);

  return [dirPath, fileName];
}

const path = "C:\\Documents\\Newsletters\\Summer2018.pdf";
const slash = "\\";

const res = splitFileNameFromPath(path, slash);

console.log(res);
console.log(path === res.join(slash));
```